# Pandas Place Columns Data into Rows of Existing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as seen below and am trying to place the existing information to other columns.

```
A   B   C
aa   bb  cc  dd  ee  ff gg hh ii .....
```

and I am trying to get the other columns of information to go under columns A-C.

```
A   B   C
aa  bb  cc  
dd  ee  ff 
gg  hh  ii
```

Any idea of how to do so? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your initial format? Is it a file? A string? A dataframe with empty column headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of columns is divisible by 3, you can use `reshape`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,3), columns=['a','b','c'])
```